# Symfony 2 - Update database on click

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I try to update the 'archive' value of the database when I click on a check box. After searching the site and google, I managed to do it.
However, by adding a second article, it only works for the first one. If you ever have ideas, I will be grateful!
Thank you
I have fosjsroutingbundle installed.

Here is my controller :

```
 public function archiveAction($id, Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $glasse = $em->getRepository('SosMontagesBundle:Glasse')->find($id);
        $glasseArchiveStat = $glasse->getArchive();

        if ($glasseArchiveStat == false) {
            $glasse->setArchive(true);
            $em->flush();
        } else {
            $glasse->setArchive(false);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return new Response('d');

    }


}
```

My route :

```
sos_montage_archive:
path:    /admin/archive/{id}
defaults: { _controller: SosMontagesBundle:Admin:archive }
requirements:
    id: \d+
options:
    expose: true
```

My view :

```
{% extends '@SosMontages/layout.html.twig' %}
```

{% block content %}

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Liste des lunettes</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Marque - Model</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Archive</th>
            <th>Ordre</th>
            <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for article in pagination %}
            <tr {% if loop.index is odd %}class="color"{% endif %}>
                <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ article.name ~ ' - ' ~ article.brand }}</td>
                <td>{{ article.content }}</td>
                {% if article.archive == false %}
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ article.id }}" id="archive"></td>
                {% else %}
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ article.id }}" id="archive" checked></td>
                {% endif %}
                <td></td>
                <td><a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="navigation">
        {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#archive").click(function () {

            var id = $("#archive").attr('name');


            var DATA = 'sentValue=' + id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Routing.generate('sos_montage_archive', { id: id }),
                data: DATA,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("database has been updated");

                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: This is basic **HTML**. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Assign a css class to those checkboxes and hook your `click` action to that instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your click listenner on your checkbox may not be correct. You should use a change listener while it's a checkbox. Change your click function in js to change:

```
$('#archive').change(function() {
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //'checked' event code
      return;
   }
   //'unchecked' event code
});
```

However you also have two checkboxes and only one id. This might create weird bugs. Changing your ids to #archive1 and #archive2 may fix your code.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.
But, my name is auto generated by the boucle for in the twig's views.

Comment: Then can you try putting #archive as a class name instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your HTML and differentiate your #archive id selector.

You can do that by using loop.index for example:

```
id="archive{{ loop.index }}" //output : archive1, archive2...
```

Twig doc :
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable